# Why can't my friends access my website built with Apache2?

Tags: apache, webserver, apache2

So, I have been building this website with HTML and I decided to host it with on Apache2. It runs on an Ubuntu and me already changed the VM assigned Ip, which is 10.2.0.15, into another one. I can access it on the Mac where the VM is, but I asked my friend if he can open it, and he said it was a 404 Server not found error. 
Please help!

Comment: 10.x.x.x is a private IP address range.  No one outside of your router will be able to see it.

Comment: yes, but I changed the adapter to be a bridged adapter

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable port forwarding:

https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/

You haven't indicated what VM software you are using, but the above is for VirtualBox. VMware is a bit different. Also make sure your router is not blocking any packets or any firewall.